# Scalability Qt 5.15 Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml

Since it is incredibly difficult to find a developer of android applications for qt, I will ask a question here, suddenly someone was doing this.

How to solve the scalability problem on different devices? Ideally, the application should look the same on all screens, from m/hdmi to xhdpi, if there were only 6 types of screens, the task would be much easier, but in fact there are a huge number of phones with a variety of screen sizes, for example, 1280x2500.

Everything is clear with icons, qt under the hood takes icons from folders 20x20, 20x20@2 etc. But with the positioning and sizes of fields, buttons, etc., not everything is so simple, in any case margin and padding will be needed during development, sometimes even a static size needs to be set, but how to make them look the same is the question.

The official Qt documentation suggests using layouts, but for example on the authorization page, where there is a large logo and 2-3 fields, it is difficult to use layouts, and there are many examples of pages where layouts would be very difficult to use. If without layouts, qt suggests doing something like this:

```
height: Screen.height / 13.63321
anchors.leftMargin: Screen.width / 31.5764
```

But I'm not sure if this is the right way, it looks strange.
There is also an option to use:

```
property int dpi: Screen.pixelDensity * 25.4
```

But this method does not always work, perhaps there is some way that I do not know about.
If you have been developing for android on qt, please tell how you solved this problem?

Comment: I think the term *scalability* in informatics has a slightly different meaning, maybe you mean, uhm, GUI portability? Device agnostic GUI? Your problem it's not related to Qt, it was the first challenge of html pages when first browsers on handheld devices appeared. Aside scaling relative to screen size, sometimes the choice is to have different layouts (placement and visibility of widgets) depending on certain screen size ranges.

Comment: @MatG Yes, most likely I made a mistake with the term, but it seems to me that having separate layouts for different screens is too much work, because for example xhdpi - xxxhdpi are not so much different, and you can simply reduce/increase the size of elements for these screens, and I wonder how this is done without losing the ratios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our case, we did not want to fill entire Pad and/or TV screen, and our appraoch for handling responsive-size was to:

- Make size-preset: find our prefered screen-size-preset, on which we base all view constants (sizes).

  > We did pick 320x548, which is smallest iPhone safe-area.
- Fit-to-screen: hard-code said size-preset into a helper-class, which does calculate and resize said-constants to fit on current-screen.

  > Where we always use short-dimension (320) in calculation (but long-dimension can be used instead, at least, for views that support vertical-scroll-bar).
- Document: mention screen-preset in `README.md` file.

### Example

[image: screens]

Comment: Hmm it's kinda nice solution, thanks for answer! As I understand it, you create separate qml file with constants and when it's necessary (when anchors or layouts can't help) use them, right?

Comment: @Deymoss our views do wherever possible use a percentage of their parent-view, and wherever that's not possible (like root-view which includes all other views), the code (no matter if QML or C++) does pass a constant to said helper-class and uses returned value.

Comment: @Deymoss It's good to follow loose-coupling convention, but we shoud not forget about cohesion convention (which is about putting together what should not be separated).

Comment: thank you very much for your experience, I will try to implement something similar, I don't really understand how to use the percentage, but as I understand it, this is division which depends on the screen size and the desired size of the element, in any case, everything is more or less clear, thank you!

Comment: @Deymoss The idea behind percentage is that, the parent-view is already re-sized based on current-screen-size, hence we only need to choose (design) how much of parent-view (in percentage) the child-view should take.